# ASP.NET Core 2.0 SignInAsync without principal

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to follow the IdentityServer4 Quickstart Samples to setup my idP for Amazon Alexa, but the sample was not made for .NET Core 2.0.

Specifically, the following line:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props);
```

Is no longer present. It appears to have been replaced by the `IAuthenticationService`- However, this service requires a ClaimsPrincipal rather than just an id/username.

How can I sign in a user without more information? Or am I doing something wrong when my only goal is to acquire an authorization code?

I've used the samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples) and [here](https://github.com/bayardw/IdentityServer4.Authorization.Code), but they both appear to be based on the same code.

Any suggestion or samples of the authorization code flow would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>`, which did the trick. `_signinManager` is injected by the ASP.NET Core DI container.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
AuthenticationProperties props = null;
await _signinManager.SignInAsync(user, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue now it's likely due to - [HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName) #4546](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4546)

Basically, the Quick Start UI has been updated to use a new extension method of SignInAsync() that takes an `IdentityServerUser` object.

> See our updated UI - this has all the changes you are asking about...e.g.
>
> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/main/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L114-L121

It basically boils down to replacing your `SignInAsync()` line with;

```cs
// issue authentication cookie for user
var user = new IdentityServerUser(model.SubjectId)
{
  DisplayName = model.Username
};
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user, props);
```